# Exchange Server and SAS 9.1.3/9.2

Tags: exchange-server, sas

has anyone successfully interacted with a microsoft exchange server in SAS 9.1.3 or 9.2? i know it can be done with SAS Ent. Guide 4.x, but i'm not interested in that route if regular SAS can do it.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault? http://serverfault.com/

Comment: no. i don't think so. i want to access an exchange server from the sas environment (old-school sas dms, thank you).

Comment: What kind of interactions?  Do you mean check mail for an inbox, that kind of thing?

Comment: i was wanting to work messages (do text analysis on messages with certain tags, simple descriptives by sender, etc.) as well as query the address book.

this was something of a passing interest to me. filed under "this would make a good SAS Global Forum paper".

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to get it done
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/086-2010.pdf

The idea is to create an access database to your emails and then read the data off that access database!

Comment: this certainly seems like it would get at what I wanted to get at all those years ago ;)